# Logrotate not installed as a systemd service

Tags: logging, systemd, apt, aptitude, logrotate

I have installed via `apt` `logrotate`.

However I don't see any `systemd` service.

Does this requires a separate process for setting up `logrotate` as a `systemd` service?

```
root@myserver:~# apt install -y logrotate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
logrotate is already the newest version (3.11.0-0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
root@myserver:~# systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i logro
```

Working on `Debian 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logrotate package in Debian 9 only supported cron – `dpkg -L logrotate` should show a file in `/etc/cron.*`.

In general, Debian 9 only had partial systemd support.

Meanwhile, the same package in Debian 11 *does* install a systemd `.timer` unit for the scheduled task (logrotate.timer, which periodically starts logrotate.service).